# I need to write a sp that will insert the characters after the first 4000 characters on the second line

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a column named 'Products' and its VARCHAR2(4000). In some cases I send more characters than 4000. It looks like '1,2,3,4,5,6...'. How can i insert first 4000 characters into one row and insert remaining to another row but of course it should consider the comma.

I tried to use array system but couldnt figure it out.

Comment: Storing data as comma separated values will cause you lots of problems.

Comment: In relational structures different rows generally represent different entities. It's quite strange to store irrelevant piece of some information just to emulate line breaks because I presume you need an entire concatenated value. Use `clob` for this purpose which wil allow less than 4k bytes to be stored in the same segment because `enable storage in row` is a default storage parameter value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use comma-demilited strings.

If you are going to store relational data then use another table.

If you are currently using:

```sql
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  id          NUMBER
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              PRIMARY KEY,
  product_ids VARCHAR2(4000)
);
```

Then change it to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE main_table (
  id          NUMBER
              GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
              PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE main_table_products (
  id         REFERENCES main_table (id),
  product_id NUMBER
             -- Assuming you have a products table
             REFERENCES products (id),
  CONSTRAINT main_table_products__pk PRIMARY KEY (id, product_id)
);
```

Then you know:

- The `product_id`s are all the correct data type,
- You have referential constraints insuring that the `product_id`s are valid products.
- You do not have duplicate `product_id`s for each `id` as the primary key prevents it.
- You can insert any number of `product_id`s.
- You can easily delete or update `product_id`s.

If you use a delimited `VARCHAR2` string then you do not (out-of-the-box) have any of those benefits.